# Is it possible to compile php extension like phalcon without root permissions?

Tags: php, php-extension, phalcon

I'm just wondering is it possible to compile php extension like phalcon without root privilage?

I'd like to be able to use phalcon on virtual hosting where I have ssh access also gcc and other compilers installed.

Is it possible to compile extension and just apply settings in php.ini? Or php extensions require some special privilages I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you could compile phalcon without root permissions, but you would need root permissions to make the extension available to apache or nginx or whatever your web server is.